# Handle MSPointer(Down|Move|Up) events in Dart

Tags: windows-phone-7, dart

Using a few sources I was able to attach a handler to the MSPointer events on a Windows Phone 8 but the 'event' provided in the handler didn't appear to have any common Event or CustomEvent properties.

Examples of how to connect to the pointer events:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/fbf58663-7735-400f-a731-154dbc2862cc/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/19/handling-multi-touch-and-mouse-input-in-all-browsers.aspx

JS library to unify touch events across several devices:

https://github.com/borismus/pointer.js/blob/master/js/pointer.js?#L163

Led to CSS (on body):

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
```

Dart:

```
_target.on['MSPointerDown'].listen(_onMSPointerDown);
```

and:

```
void _onMSPointerDown(Event event) {
    // got ms pointer down <- gets here
    // Both of below lines throw Method Not Found errors...
    var type = event.type;
    var type = event.pointerType;
}
```

Any ideas on why the event would not carry valid property data?

I haven't done much JS-interop so it might be something I'm missing there also...